# How do I save a mongodb document with my own ID field and Js date field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I am creating a POST endpoint which whose request and response should be in the below format. I have used mongoose to define balance and name field in the schema. How do I add the date and Id field in the response.
[image]

I tried passing in
{id: uuidv4(),date: new Date()}
to the db save method.

Comment: Please include some code to demonstrate what you have tried and the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the entity is configured correctly, mongodb automatically generates an id as well as the createdAt/updatedAt fields by inheriting from the Document class. For the example here, I use the Nest.js framework (you can create a similar model without decorators)

```js
@Schema()
export class SomeEntity extends Document {
  @Prop({ required: false })
  balance: number;

  @Prop({ required: false })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, default: uuidv4() })
  transctionId: string;
}

export const SomeSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(SomeEntity)
```

You can also specify additional date fields for easy access

```js
@Schema()
    export class SomeEntity extends Document {
      @Prop({ required: false })
      balance: number;

      @Prop({ required: false })
      name: string;

      @Prop({ required: true, default: uuidv4() })
      transctionId: string;

      createdAt: Date;

      updatedAt: Date;
    }

export const SomeSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(SomeEntity)
```

When creating an entity, only the required fields should be specified. The result will return you a complete created entity with all the fields

```
 const newSubject = new this.someEntity({
    balance: yourBalance,
    name: yourName,
  });

  return await newSubject.save();
```

You can immediately destructure the necessary fields and return them separately

```
 const {_id, createdAt, updatedAt} = await newSubject.save();

 return {_id, createdAt, updatedAt}
```

Notice how the mongodb '_id' looks like